# Is it natural to use the word 'through' like this?

Tags: grammar, synonyms

Sentences with the word 'through':

'You can only do that *through* hard work' (you can only do that *by virtue of* hard work)
'He accomplished that *through* sheer dedication' (he accomplished that *using* sheer dedication)
'Succeed *through* intelligence' (succeed *with**/using* intelligence)

From what it seems to me, the word 'through' here means something like 'by virtue of/using/with'. Is that right? And is it correct and natural to use it like that in all of those sentences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's completely natural.
[Merriam-Webster *through*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/through)

> preposition
> 2  —used as a function word to indicate means, agency, or intermediacy: such as
> a : by means of : by the agency of

Or, [American Heritage Dictionary *through*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=through)

> 10. Because of; on account of: *She succeeded through hard work. He declined the honor through modesty.*

All of your example sentences are natural. (The last sentence is a little mysterious, but it's a natural expression.)

There are only so many prepositions, so they all have a lot of uses and meanings.